# goncharov - number of cycles in random permutations

Tags: reference-request, permutations, normal-distribution

I see the following two cited very often, but was only able to find the second one in Russian.

V. Goncharov, Sur la distribution des cycles dans les permutations, C. R. (Doklady)
Acad. Sei. URSS (N.S) 35 (1942), 267-269.

V. Goncharov, Du domaine d'analyse combinatoire, Bull. Acad. Sei. USSR Ser. Mat. (Izv.
Akad. Nauk SSSR) 8 (1944), 3-48; Amer. Math. Soc. Transi. (2) 19 (1962), 1-46.

Does anyone know where I can find these books/papers (preferably in English or French)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may not find the first one except as a one-off if someone has translated it and put it online. Here is the history of the translations of Doklady (Soviet Academy of Sciences) journals from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proceedings_of_the_USSR_Academy_of_Sciences). Originally there were translations in the 30's I take it from the complicated description there, presumably interrupted by the war.

> English translations of "Doklady" articles began again in 1956, when the American Institute of Physics began publishing Soviet Physics - Doklady. Other publications soon followed and within a few years most Doklady subject sections were available in English translation.

> Doklady translation journals are as of 2013 published by Pleiades Publishing, Ltd and distributed online by Springer Science+Business Media. The online translation journals now only publish "selected" articles from the original Russian-language journal, which is also available online from 2006.[10]

The search link on the official page yielded nothing for me but you may do a more careful serach:

https://www.mathnet.ru/php/search.phtml?jrnid=dan&tjrnid=dan&wshow=search&option_lang=eng